# Does water have shear thinning property?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, elasticity

I'm working on a project and I need to know if the water is viscoelastic?
does water have shear thinning property?

Comment: Water is neither viscoelastic nor shear thinning.

Comment: Water is a purely Newtonian fluid: not viscoelastic at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general shear thinning occurs when the fluid has some internal structure that changes with shear rate. For example polymer solutions generally show shear thinning because at high shear rates the polymer chains change their conformation to align with the flow.

Water molecules are pretty close to spherical. If you plot the electron density of a water molecule (I did this for an undergrad project) you find the two hydrogen atoms make only small bumps in the electron density. The result is that water behaves pretty much like a Newtonian fluid and does not shear thin.

I use the escape clause *pretty much* because in the past there were claims that at very, very low shear rates the hydrogen bonding could form extended structures that increased the viscosity. I don't think these claims have stood the test of time, but I'm reluctantly to swear under oath that there is no such effect. However we are talking about shear rates that are extremely low - far lower than you'd ever meet outside specialist viscometers.